# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

include('db.php');
include('cLogin.php');

$username = "";
$isFollowing = False;
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        if (DB::query('SELECT u FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))) {
                $username = DB::query('SELECT u FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['u'];
                if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {

                    if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
                                        DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (\'\', :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                } else {
                                        echo 'Already following!';
                                }

                        $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
                        if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
                                DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (\'\', :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                        } else {
                                #echo 'Already following!';
                            $isFollowing = True;
                        }
                $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
                        $isFollowing = True;
                }
                if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {
                        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
                                        DB::query('DELETE FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                }
                                $isFollowing = False;
                        }
                }
        } else {
                die('User not found!');
        }
}
?>
<title>Gamerfile of <?php echo $username; ?> // GamersCafe</title>
<h1><?php echo $username; ?>'s GamerFile</h1>
<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
<?php
        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                if ($isFollowing) {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="unfollow" value="Unfollow">';
                } else {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
                }
        }
?>
</form>
```

I was coding a social network profile page the other day (the code is above), and I got this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xamppp\htdocs\gamerscafe\profile.php on line 57
What did I do wrong? I checked some other questions, and they apparently used short open tags, but as you can see, I didn't, so that's weird.

EDIT: I don't know what I forgot in the file, so if somebody can figure out what's wrong, that would be helpful. Thanks!

EDIT 2: I fixed it by putting in a curly bracket!

Comment: One of your conditionals is not closed correctly. The line number is not useful with these errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

include('db.php');
include('cLogin.php');

$username = "";
$isFollowing = False;
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
        if (DB::query('SELECT u FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))) {
                $username = DB::query('SELECT u FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['u'];
                if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {

                    if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
                                        DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (\'\', :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                } else {
                                        echo 'Already following!';
                                }

                        $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
                        if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
                                DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (\'\', :userid, :followerid)', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                        } else {
                                #echo 'Already following!';
                            $isFollowing = True;
                        }
                $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE u=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                        $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
                        $isFollowing = True;
                }
                if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {
                        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid))) {
       DB::query('DELETE FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                }
                                $isFollowing = False;
                        }
                }
        } else {
                die('User not found!');
        }
}}
?>
<title>Gamerfile of <?php echo $username; ?> // GamersCafe</title>
<h1><?php echo $username; ?>'s GamerFile</h1>
<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post">
<?php
        if ($userid != $followerid) {
                if ($isFollowing) {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="unfollow" value="Unfollow">';
                } else {
                        echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
                }
        }
?>
</form>
```

The `if (isset($_GET['username'])) {` closing brace is not closed.